# Integer sequence generated by using transcendental numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Given the integer sequence in which the $n^{\rm th}$ term is defined by:

$$
f(n)=\lfloor nt \rfloor,
$$

where $t$ is a transcendental number and $n$ is a positive integer, are infinitely many terms of the sequence comprime?

More specifically, which terms of the sequence are coprime, and how may one go about proving/disproving such a property? It seems like Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions is the way to go, but the presence of the floor function and transcendetal numbers is a big hurdle.

In general, what can be said about the co-primality of the terms in such sequences?

Idem for the functions:

- $f(n)=\lfloor n^t\rfloor$,
- $f(n)=\lfloor t^n\rfloor$.

Comment: Could you specify the term "comprime"? If you mean coprime, I see no reason why they should be - it should be rather easy to choose $t$ such that every positive integer appears in the sequence, so also non-coprime ones.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold What about $t=e$ or $r\pi$, where $r\in\mathbb{N⁺}$? Is it known whether the terms are coprime, or *which* terms are coprime?

Comment: Run a program computing your numbers. If you find a transcendental number such that even the first ten, or the first 100 terms are all different and coprime, that would be a really big surprise - come back and share that number and we will try to figure out how that happened. ;)

Comment: @DirkLiebhold I see your point. I updated my question.

Comment: _Coprime_ is defined for two numbers, not infinitely many. Did you mean _pairwise coprime_?

Comment: @IvanNeretin That is correct. But since coprime is already defined for two numbers, the word pairwise is redundant.

Comment: No it isn't. Say, the numbers $6,10,15$ are _coprime in general_ (meaning there is no non-trivial divisor common to all three), but not pairwise coprime.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You said "since coprime is already defined for two numbers", now you say "No it isn't". Which is it?

Comment: It is you who said that. Anyway, my "no" was referring to "the word is redundant" part.

Comment: What's the motivation to having $t$ be transcendental as opposed to just irrational?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean : Are infinite many of the numbers prime ? This would be an interesting question!

Comment: $f(n)=\lfloor t^n\rfloor$ is trivially false for any $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Comment: @Peter Yes! Actually, wouldn't that be an equivalent question? If there are infinite primes in the sequence, that means that by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic sequences, there is an infinity number of coprime integers in teh sequence.

Comment: @orlp What about $f(n)=\lfloor t^n\rfloor$ for $t>1$? These cases are the really interesting ones. Can you please expand on your second statement? Perhaps include these cases in an answer?

Comment: Distinct primes are always coprime (not just pairwise coprime), but "arbitary many pairwise coprime numbers" would be a weaker statement. And Dirichlet's theorem is about primes : "If $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers, then there are infinite many primes of the form $an+b$".

Comment: @Pickle I removed the second statement because I was thinking of the wrong thing.

Comment: Do I understand the negative of "infinitely many terms of the sequence coprime" correctly? For each element $i$ in the sequence there must be an element $j$ in the sequence such that all elements after $j$ have a shared common divisor with all elements before $i$? In plain words: later elements in the sequence must be incredibly, incredibly composite numbers?

Comment: @Pickle Coprime only makes sense in the case of at least two numbers, whether "pairwise coprime" or just "coprime". A single number always has a "common factor", the number itself , if it is greater than $1$. For a single prime number, you should use the name "prime" rather than "coprime".

Comment: $f(n)=\lfloor n^t\rfloor$ is trivially true if you start the sequence at $n=1$, because the sequence contains $1$, meaning infinitely many other numbers are coprime to it. The same applies to $f(n)=\lfloor nt \rfloor$ with $0 < t < 2$.

Comment: @Sophie The same as any other field in mathematics: curiosity. The question "why X not Y" is not a very useful one.

Comment: @orlp _"Infinitely many coprime pairs"_ is a somewhat weaker statement than _"infinitely many pairwise coprime terms"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}$
Let's reason about the negative. Suppose that for some $t$ only finitely many terms of $\fl{tn}$ are coprime with some other term. Then there must be some constant integer $s$ and constant integer common divisor $d > 1$ such that $\fl{t(n+s)} = dm$ for all $n>0$.

Now write $i = \fl t$ and $x = t - i$. Then we have:

$$\fl{(i + x)(n+s)} = dm$$
$$\fl{x(n+s)} = dm - i(n+s)$$

But also
$$\fl{x(n+s+1)} = dm' - i(n+s+1)$$

Subtracting these two we find:

$$\fl{x(n+s+1)} - \fl{x(n+s)} = d(m'-m) - i$$

If we look at this equation $\bmod d$ we find:

$$\fl{x(n+s+1)} - \fl{x(n+s)} =  - i$$

Since $0 \leq x < 1$, the left hand side can only take on values $1$ and $0$. And for any $x > 0$, the left hand side varies between $0$ and $1$ infinitely often for various $n$. But the right hand side is constant, therefore $x = 0$ and thus $t$ must be integer.